# How to get top row using orderby and partition by in linq to sql

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

```
Table
id | name | score
-----------------
3  | jim  | 2
4  | jim  | 1
5  | jim  | 3
6  | Ace  | 2
7  | Ace  | 1
```

I want to return 2 records with most score. Ace with 2 and Jim with 3.
I did this in sql but i cannot seem to convert it properly in linq.
SQl query:

```
SELECT *
      FROM   (SELECT Row_number() 
                       OVER( 
                         partition BY name
                         ORDER BY score DESC) AS rn, 
                     score, 
                     id, 
                     name, 
              FROM  table ) AS a 
      WHERE  rn = 1
```

Here is what i started in linq:

```
ctx.records.GroupBy(r => r.name).Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(i => i.score)).ToList();
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: ctx.records.OrderByDescending(r => r.score).GroupBy(r => r.name).Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();

Comment: @jdweng that did it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way, Live demo [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2YWBpP)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var records = new []
        {
            new Record { id = 3, name = "jim", score = 2 },
            new Record { id = 4, name = "jim", score = 1 },
            new Record { id = 5, name = "jim", score = 3 },
            new Record { id = 6, name = "Ace", score = 2 },
            new Record { id = 7, name = "jim", score = 1 }
        };

        var result = records.GroupBy(p => p.name)
                            .Select(g => new { Name = g.Key, Score = g.Max(p => p.score) })
                            .ToList();
        foreach(var item in result)
            Console.WriteLine("Name: " + item.Name + " Score: " + item.Score);
    }

    public class Record
    {
        public int id {get; set;}
        public string name  {get; set;}
        public int score {get; set;}

    }
}
```